# How to stop EditText keyboard from jumping to top of screen

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I'm developing a chat app and i have a problem when the user  inputs a new message using edit text the android keyboard jumps to the top of the screen ,is there a way to control this?

Comment: Top of the screen? Do u mean hides the editText?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your keyboard and also add your code?

Comment: it scrolls to to the top of recycler view

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to your XML in parent element

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

and this to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

finally add this to your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

I hope it will help you .